# MsBuild run Exec for every item in a list

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to load a list of filenames from a text file and then run an Exec task for each entry retrieved from the text file.

So I have a file, let's call it SomeFile.txt containing the following:

```
FileA.file
FileB.file
FileC.file
```

The MsBuild code I have for this looks like this (which doesn't work:)

```
<Target Name="runScripts">  

    <ItemGroup>
        <scriptsFile Include="SomeFile.txt" />
    </ItemGroup>        

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="@(scriptsFile)">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="scriptItems" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <Message Text="Running Exec for each entry..." />           
    <Exec Command="$(someCommand) %(scriptItems)" />

</Target>
```

This gives me an error saying I need to specify an item name, but if I use anything like %(scriptItems.item) or %(itemname.scriptItems) MsBuild simply puts a blank instead of %(scriptItems).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simply need to use `%(scriptItems.Identity)` to get an item name from the metadata. This is well documented at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata).